# plotly: how to make a standalone plot in a window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

Is there any way to use plotly just like matplotlib, that is, making the plot appear in a pop up window? Eg, is there an simple equivalent of

```
plt.plot([1,2,3], [2, 3, 2.5])
plt.show()
```

I've tried various functions, but all of them seem to either create an html file or an image file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Show in system image viewer

You can open the image that is created by plotly in your default system image viewer, which is kind of a standalone window.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=np.random.rand(100), y=np.random.rand(100), mode='markers',
                marker={'size': 30, 'color': np.random.rand(100), 'opacity': 0.6, 
                        'colorscale': 'Viridis'});

def show(fig):
    import io
    import plotly.io as pio
    from PIL import Image
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    pio.write_image(fig, buf)
    img = Image.open(buf)
    img.show() 

show(fig)
```

The drawback of this is of course that you don't have any interaction.

### Create browser window

The alternative can be to create a webbrowser window to show the html page generated by plotly. To this end you need to make use of a GUI toolkit that allows to create a browser. PyQt5 would be one.

So the following creates a PyQt5 window with a browser and loads the html page created by plotly inside of it for you to interact with. (This is tested with pyqt 5.9, it may not work with much older versions.)

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go


fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=np.random.rand(100), y=np.random.rand(100), mode='markers',
                marker={'size': 30, 'color': np.random.rand(100), 'opacity': 0.6, 
                        'colorscale': 'Viridis'});


def show_in_window(fig):
    import sys, os
    import plotly.offline
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    
    plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='name.html', auto_open=False)
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = QWebEngineView()
    file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "name.html"))
    web.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(file_path))
    web.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


show_in_window(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: so, no native plotly way, you have to find a workaround?

Comment: "Native plotly way" would mean that plotly would need to decide for a GUI toolkit (or for several, like matplotlib does) and provide some rendering engine for it(them). However, plotly's focus lies in rendering to the browser. I doubt there is interest from the plotly side to dive into all the desktop GUI stuff.

Comment: That's great. When running this code from Jupyter notebook, the external window does open but it blocks the notebook till the plot window is closed. Is there any way to keep interacting (something like web.show(block=False)?)

Comment: @Matan_ma This would be pretty hard because you need to have the Qt main loop and the jupyter main loop running both at the same time.

Comment: In jupyter `__file__` is not defined, but replacing `os.path.dirname(__file__)` by `'.'` works .

Answer (score 10):

This should be simple as

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "browser"
```

Source: https://plotly.com/python/renderers/

Comment: `fig.show(renderer="browser")` indeed opens a new tab filled with the plot. Maximizing or going full-screen makes the plot scale accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: fantastic! insanely simple

Comment: @arielCo Interesting! But I get `TypeError: show() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'` from a `fig` that comes from `matplotlib.__version__ = 3.4.3`. What version are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a standalone class made from ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer incase anyone needs that

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=np.random.rand(100), y=np.random.rand(100), mode='markers',
                marker={'size': 30, 'color': np.random.rand(100), 'opacity': 0.6,
                        'colorscale': 'Viridis'});

import os, sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets


class PlotlyViewer(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, fig, exec=True):
        # Create a QApplication instance or use the existing one if it exists
        self.app = QApplication.instance() if QApplication.instance() else QApplication(sys.argv)

        super().__init__()

        self.file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "temp.html"))
        plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename=self.file_path, auto_open=False)
        self.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.file_path))
        self.setWindowTitle("Plotly Viewer")
        self.show()

        if exec:
            self.app.exec_()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        os.remove(self.file_path)


win = PlotlyViewer(fig)
```