# Integrating Plotly inside WxPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, plotly

Plotly says it is a web library. Matplotlib does support Wxpython but comparatively, it is too low level. Is there any way to integrate Plotly inside a Wxpython GUI or are there any alternative for it?

Comment: You can [easily integrate matplotlib in wxpython](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx5_sgskip.html). Plotly in turn is web based. You may create a webbrowser in wx to show plotly output though (probably using something like `wx.html2.WebView`). Something similar has been shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570384/plotly-how-to-make-a-standalone-plot-in-a-window/53573039#53573039) for PyQt instead of wx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use Plotly's ability to export plots to images to get the plots into wxPython:

- https://plot.ly/python/offline/#static-image-export

If you need the live plotting though, then you will need to use Webview:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.html2.WebView.html

I also see that Plotly can now be used offline, so if you used that plus Webview, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Wxpython webview doesn't support 3-d graphs from plotly.
For 3-d graphs, I used [cefpython](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/). It embeds a full chromium browser inside python application. wxpython example can be found here: https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/wxpython.py.
I used plotly offline, and read the file inside cefpython.

Comment: Do you have an example for using offline plotly inside cefpython?

Comment: @bs0d it wasn't special to plotly. I used plotly to write files and read them using cefpython as it would read any other html.