# PySide6 as a process in a script

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyside6

I am running a data analysis script and I much prefer plotly to matplotlib.  I am curious if it is possible to do the same figure windows like in matplotlib without blocking the script.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570384/plotly-how-to-make-a-standalone-plot-in-a-window) gave the following code that generates a WebEngineWindget (I used PySide6 here) with an offline plotly chart

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=np.random.rand(100), y=np.random.rand(100), mode='markers',
                marker={'size': 30, 'color': np.random.rand(100), 'opacity': 0.6,
                        'colorscale': 'Viridis'});

import os, sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide6 import QtWebEngineWidgets


class PlotlyViewer(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, fig, exec=True):
        # Create a QApplication instance or use the existing one if it exists
        self.app = QApplication.instance() if QApplication.instance() else QApplication(sys.argv)

        super().__init__()

        self.file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "temp.html"))
        plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename=self.file_path, auto_open=False)
        self.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.file_path))
        self.setWindowTitle("Plotly Viewer")
        self.show()

        if exec:
            self.app.exec()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        os.remove(self.file_path)


win = PlotlyViewer(fig)
```

My question is how I can do this without blocking my script.  If I do

```
win = PlotlyViewer(fig)
win2 = PlotlyViewer(fig2)
win3 = PlotlyViewer(fig3)
```

Then win2 doesnt pop up until the first one is closed.  I understand I could make a widget that has 3 instead, but sometimes I am just looking at 1 plot, other times more, so I am curious if I can run as a process that would keep executing.  Or have I run into the thing I read everywhere where the GIL turns people away from python?

Comment: create one `QApplication` and pass it to `__init__` for each instance, then call `app.exec()`, and all of them will run at the same time. (ie: don't do this inside `__init__` of your main window unless that's the only window). Basically calling `exec` is what starts the event loop for a gui, and blocks until you're done with that gui. you therefore need one event loop that encompases all your windows.

Comment: Actually, you shall not need to pass a QApplication at all: QWebEngineView is a QWidget, and, as such, can only be created as long as a QApplication exists, so the existence of the QApplication is implicit. Conceptually speaking: since you can only create it as long as a QApplication exists, there's no point in checking for it: it should just exist *prior* to that. The real question here are: 1. why do you need to create and run a QApplication "on demand"? 2. what would trigger the creation of a PlotlyViewer instance?

Comment: So basically my question is if I can do this to replace a plt.figure().  On our analysis, we have that we can have some flags that'll create additional plots (like normalized vs non normalized).  We also have some conditionals.  `if data meets some condition: do another plot`